# NodeJS - Giving public access to 'public' folder

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to give public access to a folder in NodeJS.

Here is my app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const session = require('express-session');

//const con = require('./database');
const errorController = require('./controllers/error');

const app = express(); // express framework starts

// Use the view engine => EJS
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');

const homeRouter = require('./routes/home');
const authRouter = require('./routes/auth');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
// give public access to public folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// Initialize the session
app.use(session({
    secret: 'mySecret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    rolling: true,
    cookie: {
        expires: 1000*60
    }
}));

app.use(homeRouter);
app.use(authRouter);

// If nothing was found (Wrong URL)
//app.use(errorController.get404);

app.listen(3000);
```

When I try to access: http://localhost:3000/public/css/login.css it returns: Cannot GET /public/css/login.css

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the public directory is omited in the url, then try:

http://localhost:3000/css/login.css

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Do you know why the directory is omitted?

Comment: so hide to www which path in your server holds those files.